# "no data" result from raster calculator

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, nodata, conditional, debugging

Am trying to implement the following line in QGIS raster calculator:

```
("L@1" <  0) * ((1 - 16 * 200 / "L@1")^0.25) + ("L@1" >= 0) * 1
```

Basically, when `L` is less than zero, it should compute a result using equation `((1 - 16 * 200 / "L@1")^0.25)`, and simply return 1 when `L` is greater than 0.

However, "no-data" for some cells where `L` is greater than (or equal) to zero. Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you try the new if conditional, available in QGIS raster calculator since QGIS 3.22?

Comment: @TomazicM figured it out. Some cells were being divided by zero.